# Programmatically open File Manager app with selected Downloads folder in Android R

Tags: android, deprecation-warning

I work on some legacy launcher app and need to adjust it to Android R requirements. One of the things is opening file manager that opens Downloads folder. So, until Android R, Downloads folder is opening like this:

```
val fileManagerDownloadIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
val fileManagerDownloadUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path)
fileManagerDownloadIntent.setDataAndType(fileManagerDownloadUri, "text/csv")
context.startActivity(fileManagerDownloadIntent)
```

but I receive the warning message

> getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String!): File!' is deprecated.

Actually, it is deprecated for SDK >= R. I tried to find another solution on how to get the path of the Downloads folder without any luck.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Put in extra INITIAL_URI the uri of a file previously choosen from Download directory.

Comment: But what if I don't have any file, device is just unoboxed and launcher is the first thing installed?

Comment: Then you are out of luck.